# For loop in Scrapy return nothing or the same data

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm completly new in Scrapy & Python and I really need your help. (Excuse my English too I speak Español).

My problem is: I need to scrap data from the site http://www.icreson.gob.mx/PAGINANUEVA/sala/index.php?Sala=HERMOSILLO I need pass various parameters, one of them is "inscripcion" that is used to identified the information that I looking for. The first data returned  is in http://www.icreson.gob.mx/PAGINANUEVA/sala/inscripciones.php Then I need change to another three links, to complete all data I need to scrap:

> ```
> .../PAGINANUEVA/sala/anotaciones.php,
> .../PAGINANUEVA/sala/bien_inmueble.php,
> .../PAGINANUEVA/sala/usuario.php
> ```

I make a for loop increasing the "inscripcion" number (i in the for) and when it's only one in range(368610,368611), it works great, it return the correct data. But if I passed two or more numbres in range(368610,368618) the data returned it's empty or the same.

This is the code in **items.py**:

```
from scrapy import Field
from scrapy import Item

class Ejemplo2Item(Item):
    inscripcion = Field()
    existe_inscripcion = Field()
    num_insc = Field()
    anotacion = Field()
    bien = Field()
    usuario = Field()
```

The code in the **spider in icre_sp.py** is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy import Spider
from ejemplo2.items import Ejemplo2Item
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import Selector

def _limpiar(cantidad):  
    if cantidad:
        if '$' in cantidad:
            cantidad = cantidad.replace('$', '')
        if ',' in cantidad:
            cantidad = cantidad.replace(',', '')
        if '.' in cantidad:
            cantidad = cantidad.split('.')[0]
        if cantidad.isdigit():
            cantidad = int(cantidad)
        return cantidad
    else:
        return 0


class Ejemplo2Spider(Spider):
    name = 'gsf'
    start_urls = ['http://www.icreson.gob.mx/PAGINANUEVA/sala/index.php?ban=1&Sala=',]

    def parse(self, response):

        for i in range(368612,368622):
            h = str(i)
            item = Ejemplo2Item()
            item['num_insc'] = h
            yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                            formname='MiFormulario',
                                            formdata={'instituto': '1', 
                                                    'area': 'LIBRO 1',
                                                    'inscripcion': h},
                                            cookies={'PHPSESSID':'f92c499925f059eb04b8045290011eda',
                                                    '_ga': 'GA1.3.612616751.1438557988'},
                                            meta={'item': item},
                                            dont_filter=True,
                                            method='POST',
                                            callback=self.parseInsc)

    def parseInsc(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        if "LO SIENTO NO SE PUEDE" in response.body:
            item['existe_inscripcion'] = 'NO'
            return item

        valores = response.xpath('//input/@value').extract()
        claves = response.xpath('//input/@name').extract()
        v_text = response.xpath("//textarea/text()").extract()[0]
        insc = dict(zip(claves, valores))
        insc['Monto'] = _limpiar(insc['Monto'])
        insc['Fedatario'] = v_text
        item['inscripcion'] = insc
        item['existe_inscripcion'] = 'SI'

        solicitud1 = Request('http://www.icreson.gob.mx/PAGINANUEVA/sala/anotaciones.php', 
                        dont_filter=True,
                        meta={'item': item},
                        callback=self.parseAnot)
        solicitud1.meta['item'] = item
        return solicitud1

    def parseAnot(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        if "LA INSCRIPCION NO TIENE" in response.body: 
            anot = 'NO TIENE ANOTACION'
        else:
            campos = response.xpath("//input")
            son = (len(campos) - 3 ) // 5
            off_set = 0
            van = 0
            anot = []
            while True:
                if van == son:
                    break
                c1 = campos[1+off_set].xpath("@value").extract()[0]
                c2 = campos[2+off_set].xpath("@value").extract()[0]
                c3 = campos[3+off_set].xpath("@value").extract()[0]
                c4 = campos[4+off_set].xpath("@value").extract()[0]
                c5 = campos[5+off_set].xpath("@value").extract()[0]
                ren = {'a1': c1, 'a2': c2, 'a3': c3, 'a4': c4, 'a5': c5}
                anot.append(ren)
                off_set = off_set + 5
                van = van + 1

        item['anotacion'] = anot
        solicitud2 = Request('http://www.icreson.gob.mx/PAGINANUEVA/sala/bien_inmueble.php', 
                        dont_filter=True,
                        meta={'item': item}, 
                        callback=self.parseBien)
        solicitud2.meta['item'] = item
        return solicitud2

    def parseBien(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        if "NO EXISTE NINGUN BIEN" in response.body:
            bien = 'NO TIENE BIEN INMUEBLE'
        else:
            filas = response.xpath("//div[@class='mid_conten_PagNueva']/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]//tr[position()>1]")  # el .extract() al final lo convierte en lista o valor, sin eso es un tipo Selector
            son = len(filas) - 3
            bien = []
            van = 0
            for fila in filas:
                v1 = fila.xpath('./td[1]/span/text()').extract()
                v1 = v1[0] if len(v1) > 0 else ""
                v2 = fila.xpath('./td[2]/span/text()').extract()
                v2 = v2[0] if len(v2) > 0 else ""
                v3 = fila.xpath('./td[3]/span/text()').extract()
                v3 = v3[0] if len(v3) > 0 else ""
                v4 = fila.xpath('./td[4]/span/text()').extract()
                v4 = v4[0] if len(v4) > 0 else ""
                v5 = fila.xpath('./td[5]/span/text()').extract()
                v5 = v5[0] if len(v5) > 0 else ""
                v6 = fila.xpath('./td[6]/span/text()').extract()
                v6 = v6[0] if len(v6) > 0 else ""
                v7 = fila.xpath('./td[7]/span/text()').extract()
                v7 = v7[0] if len(v7) > 0 else ""
                v8 = fila.xpath('./td[8]/span/text()').extract()
                v8 = v8[0] if len(v8) > 0 else ""
                ren = {'b1': v1, 
                        'b2': v2, 
                        'b3': v3, 
                        'b4': v4, 
                        'b5': v5, 
                        'b6': v6, 
                        'b7': v7, 
                        'b8': v8
                        }
                bien.append(ren)
                van = van + 1
                if van == son:
                    break

        item['bien'] = bien
        solicitud3 = Request('http://www.icreson.gob.mx/PAGINANUEVA/sala/usuario.php', 
                        dont_filter=True,
                        meta={'item': item}, 
                        callback=self.parseUsu)
        solicitud3.meta['item'] = item
        return solicitud3

    def parseUsu(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        if "NO EXISTEN USUARIOS" in response.body:
            usua = 'NO TIENE USUARIO'
        else:
            filas = response.xpath("//div[@class='mid_conten_PagNueva']/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td/table[2]//tr[position()>1]")  # el .extract() al final lo convierte en lista o valor, sin eso es un tipo Selector
            usua = []
            for fila in filas:                                                                                 
                v1 = fila.xpath('./td[1]/span/text()').extract()
                v1 = v1[0] if len(v1) > 0 else ""
                v2 = fila.xpath('./td[2]/span/text()').extract()
                v2 = v2[0] if len(v2) > 0 else ""
                v3 = fila.xpath('./td[3]/span/text()').extract()
                v3 = v3[0] if len(v3) > 0 else ""
                v4 = fila.xpath('./td[4]/span/text()').extract()
                v4 = v4[0] if len(v4) > 0 else ""
                v5 = fila.xpath('./td[5]/span/text()').extract()
                v5 = v5[0] if len(v5) > 0 else ""
                v6 = fila.xpath('./td[6]/span/text()').extract()
                v6 = v6[0] if len(v6) > 0 else ""
                ren = {'u1': v1, 
                        'u2': v2, 
                        'u3': v3, 
                        'u4': v4, 
                        'u5': v5, 
                        'u6': v6
                        }
                usua.append(ren)

        item['usuario'] = usua
        return item
```

This is the result for **multiple "inscripcion" range(368612,368622)** as you can see are repeated, but it should be different all of them.

```
[{"usuario": [{"u5": "TREJO", "u4": "MOERNO", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "RITA ERNESTINA ", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "MURRIETA", "u4": "ROJO", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "MARIA EUGENIA", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "6", "b5": "360014079001", "b6": "HERMOSILLO", "b7": "600,METROS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "25", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368612", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "TREJO", "u4": "MOERNO", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "RITA ERNESTINA ", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "MURRIETA", "u4": "ROJO", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "MARIA EUGENIA", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "6", "b5": "360014079001", "b6": "HERMOSILLO", "b7": "600,METROS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "25", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368616", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "RODRIGUEZ", "u4": "CONTRERAS", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "MARIA DEL SOCORRO GUADALUPE", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "", "u4": "", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "INMOBILIARIA JACEDO, S.A. DE C.V.", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "6", "b5": "360014079001", "b6": "HERMOSILLO", "b7": "600,METROS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "25", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368621", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "TREJO", "u4": "MOERNO", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "RITA ERNESTINA ", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "MURRIETA", "u4": "ROJO", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "MARIA EUGENIA", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "6", "b5": "360014079001", "b6": "HERMOSILLO", "b7": "600,METROS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "25", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368617", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "TREJO", "u4": "MOERNO", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "RITA ERNESTINA ", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "MURRIETA", "u4": "ROJO", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "MARIA EUGENIA", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "6", "b5": "360014079001", "b6": "HERMOSILLO", "b7": "600,METROS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "25", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368615", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "RODRIGUEZ", "u4": "CONTRERAS", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "MARIA DEL SOCORRO GUADALUPE", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "", "u4": "", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "INMOBILIARIA JACEDO, S.A. DE C.V.", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "6", "b5": "360014079001", "b6": "HERMOSILLO", "b7": "600,METROS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "25", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368620", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "TREJO", "u4": "MOERNO", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "RITA ERNESTINA ", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "MURRIETA", "u4": "ROJO", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "MARIA EUGENIA", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "6", "b5": "360014079001", "b6": "HERMOSILLO", "b7": "600,METROS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "25", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368618", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "RODRIGUEZ", "u4": "CONTRERAS", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "MARIA DEL SOCORRO GUADALUPE", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "", "u4": "", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "INMOBILIARIA JACEDO, S.A. DE C.V.", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "6", "b5": "360014079001", "b6": "HERMOSILLO", "b7": "600,METROS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "25", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368614", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "RODRIGUEZ", "u4": "CONTRERAS", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "MARIA DEL SOCORRO GUADALUPE", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "", "u4": "", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "INMOBILIARIA JACEDO, S.A. DE C.V.", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "FRANCISCO JAVIER CABRERA FERNANDEZ NOTARIA NO. 11- HERMOSILL", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 271000, "Fecha": "2006-09-08", "Inscripcion": "368618", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 63381", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19099"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "", "b5": "360030646005", "b6": "POLIGONO B AL NORTE DE LA CIUDAD", "b7": "40,HECTAREAS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368619", "anotacion": "NO TIENE ANOTACION"},
{"usuario": [{"u5": "RODRIGUEZ", "u4": "CONTRERAS", "u6": "S", "u1": "1", "u3": "MARIA DEL SOCORRO GUADALUPE", "u2": "EMISOR"}, {"u5": "", "u4": "", "u6": "S", "u1": "2", "u3": "INMOBILIARIA JACEDO, S.A. DE C.V.", "u2": "RECEPTOR"}], "inscripcion": {"hora": "", "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO", "Fedatario": "SALVADOR ANTONIO CORRAL MARTINEZ NOTARIA No. 28- HERMOSILLO", "Vigencia": "S", "Monto": 14800000, "Fecha": "2007-10-08", "Inscripcion": "368613", "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO", "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 27237", "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO", "Acto": "COMPRA VENTA", "Libro": "1", "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12", "Vigencia2": "19098"}, "existe_inscripcion": "SI", "bien": [{"b4": "", "b5": "360030646005", "b6": "POLIGONO B AL NORTE DE LA CIUDAD", "b7": "40,HECTAREAS", "b1": "1", "b2": "1", "b3": "", "b8": "S"}], "num_insc": "368613", "anotacion": [{"a1": "1", "a3": "2008-04-29", "a2": "HIPOTECA", "a5": "CELEBRADA CON  OPERADORA DE EMPRESAS Y SERVICIOS, S.A. DE C.V.", "a4": "N"}, {"a1": "2", "a3": "2007-02-09", "a2": "HIPOTECA", "a5": "CELEBRADA CON DINAMICA SONORENSE, S.A. DE C.V.  LAS PARTES CONVIENEN EN QUE LA HIPOTECA SE EXTIENDA A LOS INTERESES DEVENGADOS AUN CUANDO SE EXCEDA DE TRES A\u00d1OS SIN EXCEDER EL PLAZO QUE MARCA LA LEY.", "a4": "S"}, {"a1": "3", "a3": "2009-06-05", "a2": "CANCELACION DE GRAVAMEN O LIMITACION", "a5": "CANCELADA INSCRIPCION 288097, REG. INMB. LIBRO DOS", "a4": "S"}]}]
```

And this is the result for just **only one "inscripcion" in range(368612,368613)**:

```
[{
    "usuario": [{
        "u5": "RODRIGUEZ",
        "u4": "CONTRERAS",
        "u6": "N",
        "u1": "1",
        "u3": "MARIA DEL SOCORRO GUADALUPE",
        "u2": "RECEPTOR"
    }],
    "inscripcion": {
        "hora": "",
        "Poblacion": "HERMOSILLO",
        "Fedatario": "SALVADOR ANTONIO CORRAL MARTINEZ NOTARIA No. 28- HERMOSILLO",
        "Vigencia": "N",
        "Monto": 0,
        "Fecha": "2007-10-08",
        "Inscripcion": "368612",
        "Acto2": "REGISTRO INMOBILIARIO",
        "Clave": "ESCRITURA PUBLICA 27237",
        "Municipio": "HERMOSILLO",
        "Acto": "SUBDIVISION",
        "Libro": "1",
        "Fecha de Registro": "2008-05-12",
        "Vigencia2": "19098"
    },
    "existe_inscripcion": "SI",
    "bien": [{
        "b4": "",
        "b5": "360030646005",
        "b6": "POLIGONO B AL NORTE DE LA CIUDAD",
        "b7": "40,HECTAREAS",
        "b1": "1",
        "b2": "1",
        "b3": "",
        "b8": "N"
    },
    {
        "b4": "",
        "b5": "360030646011",
        "b6": "POLIGONO D AL NORTE DE LA CIUDAD",
        "b7": "5.87047,HECTAREA",
        "b1": "2",
        "b2": "1",
        "b3": "",
        "b8": "N"
    }],
    "num_insc": "368612",
    "anotacion": [{
        "a1": "1",
        "a3": "2008-05-12",
        "a2": "COMPRA VENTA",
        "a5": "VENDIDA PORCION B A FAVOR DE INMOBILIARIA JACEDO, S.A. DE C.V.",
        "a4": "S"
    },
    {
        "a1": "2",
        "a3": "2008-04-29",
        "a2": "HIPOTECA",
        "a5": "CELEBRADO OPERADORA DE EMPRESAS Y SERVICIOS, S.A. DE C.V.",
        "a4": "S"
    },
    {
        "a1": "3",
        "a3": "2009-05-08",
        "a2": "AVISO PREVENTIVO",
        "a5": "PARA LOS EFECTOS DEL ART. 64 DE LA LEY NO. 143 CATASTRAL Y REGISTRAL DEL ESTADO DE SONORA, SE HACE CONSTAR QUE QUEDO ANOTADO EL AVISO PREVENTIVO, EN VIRTUD DEL CUAL ELMER GARCIA ACOSTA, INMOBILIARIA JACEDO, S.A.\n DE C.V. CELEBRAN COMPRA VENTA SOBRE POLIGONO D1 SEGUN TESTIMONIO 29656 DE FECHA 22 ABRIL DE 2009 AUTORIZADO POR EL LIC. SALVADOR ANTONIO CORRAL NOTARIO PUBLICO NO. 28 CON RESIDENCIA EN HERMOSILLO, SON. RECIBIDO EL 23 ABRIL DE 2009 A LAS 1:00 HRS.",
        "a4": "S"
    },
    {
        "a1": "4",
        "a3": "2009-06-03",
        "a2": "COMPRA VENTA",
        "a5": "VENDIDA FRACCION D1, SUP. 5-87-04.703 HAS. A FAVOR DE INMOBILIARIA JACEDO, S.A. DE C.V.",
        "a4": "S"
    },
    {
        "a1": "5",
        "a3": "2009-06-05",
        "a2": "CANCELACION DE GRAVAMEN O LIMITACION",
        "a5": "CANCELADA INSCRIPCION 288097, REG. INMB. LIBRO DOS",
        "a4": "S"
    }]
}]
```

I have w10, python 2.7, scrapy 1.0.3.

I don't know what is missing in the code, so I appreciate all your help. Thanks!

Comment: maybe a cookies problem, try disabling it in settings: `COOKIES_ENABLED  = 0`

Comment: eLRuLL thanks, but it doesn't work, when I disable de cookies the results are an empty structure, no data. It's necessary enable the cookies because I pass tow of them in the form `cookies={'PHPSESSID':'f92c499925f059eb04b8045290011eda',
                                                    '_ga': 'GA1.3.612616751.1438557988'}`

Comment: maybe you should generate them automatically.